# How to remove multiple sub directories from a url by using rewrite rules with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite this url
`localhost/store/admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=John`
to
`localhost/store/John`
without having to move the files

I don't even know if it is possible? Please I need help. And if it is possible, where should the .htaccess located at? Should it be in the store directory?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is possible to rewrite such request just as you suggest. I doubt however that this is what you will settle with later. Because the connection from a store to a cashier is surprising ...

However, to give you a starting point, in addition to all the available tutorials you can easily find online, this might help:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?store/(\w+)$  /store/admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This assumes you are using the apache http server, which is likely since you explicitly ask for a ".htaccess" file. Obviously the rewriting module that defines these directives needs to be loaded into the http server.

You can implement such a rule in the http server's virtual host configuration. If you plan to deploy your solution to a service where you do *not* have control over that (read: a cheap hosting provider), then you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (typically called ".htaccess". Such file should be located in the folder defined as `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in the http host configuration (so typically something like `/var/www/default` or similar, check your configuration), so that folder where `http://localhost` currently points to. The file has to be readable for the http server process. And you need to enable the interpretation of such directives by means of the `AllowOverride` directive in your central http server's configuration.

It is important that you take the time to actually understand that implementation. Do not simply copy something you find here blindly, you will not learn anything that way. A good starting point to understand the details like directive, pattern, flags is the documentation of the tools you want to use, so here the rewriting module available for the apache http server. As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: It keep saying **Internal Server Error**
_The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request._. 
Do you mind telling me what that mean or how I can fix it? btw I am usually a **localhost**. (http://localhost/store/admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=John)

Comment: The http status 500 you see is just what the http server tells requesting clients. Obviously it will not name internal issues there. You, as the person operating the server should take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can read the actual issue that lead to the http status 500. My guess: you did _not_ make sure that the rewriting module is loaded as I pointed out above...

Comment: The rewriting module is loaded though. Do you mind explaining what all of this do? 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?store/(\w+)$  /store/admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=$1 [L]`

Comment: @CheaChiOuy That is a very strange question you ask there ... Did you take a look into the documentation I specifically referenced for you? So what _exactly_ is left to be explained? A `RewriteRule` operates on _incoming_ requests. If the requested URL matches the given pattern (here `^/?store/(\w+)$`) the request is rewritten to the given target (here `/store/admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=$1`). This is an _internal rewrite_ , not a redirection. The current rewriting process is terminated by the `[L]` flag, but further rewriting loops (steps) can occur.

Comment: @CheaChiOuy I asked you to take a look into your http server's error log file. What does it contain. What is the actual cause of the http status you say you receive back when making a test request?

Answer (score 0):

If the /store (http://localhost/store) is you base URL then you can try with below

**.htacces** file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /store/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/ admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=$1
RewriteRule (.*) admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=$1
```

Comment: This won't work. Sure, one can also place such a rule in a folder somewhere inside the hierarchy, though that usually makes things more complex. But there are three issues with this rule, with that matching patter `/(.*)/` you suggest: 1. the leading slash, that will _never_ match in the given example request and 2. the trailing slash that might have similar effect, depending on the setup. 3. the star operator ("*") might not be what you actually want here...  Please test your own implementation ...

Comment: Yes it is a localhost. However when I tried it, it said **Internal Server Error**
_The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request._. 
Do you mind telling me what that mean or how I can fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion due to localhost. You can add
`RewriteRule (.*)/ admin/employee/position/cashier.php?name=$1` to work properly. I update the code also.